# how to configure default X-Pack watchers

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-x-pack

After installing X-Pack for ES 5.6, several default Watchers appear in ElasticSeach/Watchers tab.

The Watchers are greyed-out and read-only. How to view/configure that Watchers? I can’t find them elasticsearch.yml config file.
[image: kibana with default watchers]

Comment: What do you want to change about them?

Comment: @AndreiStefan I would like to view config first, update email notification addresses, reconfigure some params, e.t.c.

Comment: They are, like all other watches, in an index. You get them like this: `GET .watches/_search
{
  "size" : 100
}`